# Random System Icons Appearing on Lists

Tags: custom-form, file-icons

The following icons appear at the top of a form from a SharePoint 2013 on premise list. Using latest version of Internet Explorer 11 but will also happen in other web browsers such as Firefox. The form looks fine below the red line. It's only happening for two users (that I know of so far), and only on occasion. An F5 clears the icons and the form looks normal. When the users go into edit mode, they occasionally get a blank screen and again an F5 will clear the issue.

We do have a custom InfoPath form on this list and I have tried to republish it.

We have had this working for about two years and all of the sudden this started to happen about two weeks ago, and again to only two users. We've done all the usual trouble shooting with these users like, restarting machine, clearing cache, resetting IE......

[image]

Comment: possibly a branding issue. check your browser console for any errors or css/js 404s

Answer (score 1):

In my experience those kind of issues are most of the time caused network issues. As you say it is intermittent you need to analyse traffic with fiddler on the client that is having the issues and compare it with correct results. There is probably some issue with one of the js or css files during transit. Please note that although you clear the cache on the client machine there might be some network devices (load balancer, network accelerator) that may due additional caching.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this happen.  And It is usually intermittent, but annoying.  In the user’s browser, open the F12 developer tools and refresh the page.  In the console tab you will see any errors.  And you should be well on your way to remediation.  In my case (and I highly suspect yours too) one of the following two things is happening:

1. The page itself, the layout page or the master page is also loading jQuery and causing a conflict with SharePoint’s mQuery
   And/or
2. one of the SP.SOD(*function.js*) files is not loading because of network issues or because of an error in the *function.js* file.